# On Ubuntu 18.04 my compiled cpp executable cannot find the VTK7 dependencies

Tags: c++, linux, vtk, ubuntu-18.04

On Ubuntu 18.04 the executable cannot find the vtk dependencies even though everything works on Fedora 28. Is it necessary to rebuild the executable on Ubuntu or should it work straightforward, and if so how to make it work?

I am very lost. The commands are as follows...

```
marvin@X1-18:~/Applications/UVLM/release$ uname -a
Linux X1-18 4.15.0-23-generic #25-Ubuntu SMP Wed May 23 18:02:16 UTC 2018 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
marvin@X1-18:~/Applications/UVLM/release$ which vtk
marvin@X1-18:~/Applications/UVLM/release$ which vtk7
/usr/bin/vtk7
marvin@X1-18:~/Applications/UVLM/release$ which vtk6
/usr/bin/vtk6
marvin@X1-18:~/Applications/UVLM/release$ sudo apt install vtk7
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
vtk7 is already the newest version (7.1.1+dfsg1-2).
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
marvin@X1-18:~/Applications/UVLM/release$ ldd uvlm
linux-vdso.so.1 (0x00007ffd28927000)
libgomp.so.1 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgomp.so.1 (0x00007ff03857b000)
libpthread.so.0 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpthread.so.0 (0x00007ff03835c000)
libvtkViewsContext2D.so.1 => not found
libvtkIOGeometry.so.1 => not found
libvtkRenderingContextOpenGL2.so.1 => not found
libvtkViewsCore.so.1 => not found
libvtkInteractionWidgets.so.1 => not found
libvtkInteractionStyle.so.1 => not found
libvtkIOLegacy.so.1 => not found
libvtkIOCore.so.1 => not found
libvtkRenderingContext2D.so.1 => not found
libvtkRenderingFreeType.so.1 => not found
libfreetype.so.6 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libfreetype.so.6 (0x00007ff0380a8000)
libvtkRenderingOpenGL2.so.1 => not found
libvtkRenderingCore.so.1 => not found
libvtkFiltersSources.so.1 => not found
libvtkFiltersGeneral.so.1 => not found
libvtkFiltersCore.so.1 => not found
libSM.so.6 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libSM.so.6 (0x00007ff037ea0000)
libICE.so.6 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libICE.so.6 (0x00007ff037c85000)
libX11.so.6 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libX11.so.6 (0x00007ff03794c000)
libXext.so.6 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libXext.so.6 (0x00007ff03773a000)
libXt.so.6 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libXt.so.6 (0x00007ff0374d1000)
libvtkCommonExecutionModel.so.1 => not found
libvtkCommonDataModel.so.1 => not found
libvtkCommonMisc.so.1 => not found
libvtkCommonTransforms.so.1 => not found
libvtkCommonMath.so.1 => not found
libvtkCommonCore.so.1 => not found
libstdc++.so.6 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libstdc++.so.6 (0x00007ff037143000)
libm.so.6 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libm.so.6 (0x00007ff036da5000)
libgcc_s.so.1 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgcc_s.so.1 (0x00007ff036b8d000)
libc.so.6 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6 (0x00007ff03679c000)
libdl.so.2 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libdl.so.2 (0x00007ff036598000)
/lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2 (0x00007ff0387ab000)
libpng16.so.16 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpng16.so.16 (0x00007ff036366000)
libz.so.1 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libz.so.1 (0x00007ff036149000)
libuuid.so.1 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libuuid.so.1 (0x00007ff035f42000)
libbsd.so.0 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libbsd.so.0 (0x00007ff035d2d000)
libxcb.so.1 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libxcb.so.1 (0x00007ff035b05000)
librt.so.1 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/librt.so.1 (0x00007ff0358fd000)
libXau.so.6 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libXau.so.6 (0x00007ff0356f9000)
libXdmcp.so.6 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libXdmcp.so.6 (0x00007ff0354f3000)
marvin@X1-18:~/Applications/UVLM/release$ ./uvlm
./uvlm: error while loading shared libraries: libvtkViewsContext2D.so.1: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
marvin@X1-18:~/Applications/UVLM/release$
```

also, there is a copy of the libs with the correct naming in the folder and there is the installed vtk (and my own compiled versions)

```
marvin@X1-18:~/Applications/UVLM/release$ find /usr -name 'libvtkViewsCore.so*'
marvin@X1-18:~/Applications/UVLM/release$ find /usr -name 'libvtkViewsCore.so.1*'
marvin@X1-18:~/Applications/UVLM/release$ find /usr -name 'libvtkViewsCore*'
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libvtkViewsCore-6.3.so.6.3.0
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libvtkViewsCoreTCL-6.3.so.6.3
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libvtkViewsCoreTCL-7.1.so.7.1
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libvtkViewsCoreTCL-7.1.so.7.1.1
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libvtkViewsCoreTCL-6.3.so.6.3.0
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libvtkViewsCorePython27D-6.3.so.6.3
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libvtkViewsCorePython36D-7.1.so.7.1
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libvtkViewsCore-7.1.so.7.1.1
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libvtkViewsCore-7.1.so.7.1
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libvtkViewsCorePython36D-7.1.so.7.1.1
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libvtkViewsCore-6.3.so.6.3
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libvtkViewsCorePython27D-6.3.so.6.3.0
marvin@X1-18:~/Applications/UVLM/release$ ls
libvtkalglib.so.1                       libvtkFiltersExtraction.so.1  libvtkImagingHybrid.so.1        libvtkRenderingContext2D.so.1
libvtkCommonColor.so.1                  libvtkFiltersGeneral.so.1     libvtkImagingSources.so.1       libvtkRenderingContextOpenGL2.so.1
libvtkCommonComputationalGeometry.so.1  libvtkFiltersGeometry.so.1    libvtkInteractionStyle.so.1     libvtkRenderingCore.so.1
libvtkCommonCore.so.1                   libvtkFiltersHybrid.so.1      libvtkInteractionWidgets.so.1   libvtkRenderingFreeType.so.1
libvtkCommonDataModel.so.1              libvtkFiltersModeling.so.1    libvtkIOCore.so.1               libvtkRenderingOpenGL2.so.1
libvtkCommonExecutionModel.so.1         libvtkFiltersSources.so.1     libvtkIOGeometry.so.1           libvtkRenderingVolume.so.1
libvtkCommonMath.so.1                   libvtkFiltersStatistics.so.1  libvtkIOImage.so.1              libvtksys.so.1
libvtkCommonMisc.so.1                   libvtkglew.so.1               libvtkIOLegacy.so.1             libvtkViewsContext2D.so.1
libvtkCommonSystem.so.1                 libvtkImagingColor.so.1       libvtkIOXMLParser.so.1          libvtkViewsCore.so.1
libvtkCommonTransforms.so.1             libvtkImagingCore.so.1        libvtkIOXML.so.1                uvlm
libvtkDICOMParser.so.1                  libvtkImagingFourier.so.1     libvtkmetaio.so.1               uvlm_old
libvtkFiltersCore.so.1                  libvtkImagingGeneral.so.1     libvtkRenderingAnnotation.so.1  uvlm_old_1
```

Addition after some good inputs this method seems to work with some line by line effort. first two libs replaced.

```
marvin@X1-18:~/Applications/UVLM/release$ patchelf --replace-needed libvtkViewsContext2D.so.1 libvtkIOGeometry-7.1.so.7.1 uvlm
marvin@X1-18:~/Applications/UVLM/release$ patchelf --replace-needed libvtkIOGeometry.so.1 libvtkIOGeometry-7.1.so.7.1 uvlm
marvin@X1-18:~/Applications/UVLM/release$ ./uvlm ../ParametricDefinition/param_result_workshop_case6.json 
./uvlm: error while loading shared libraries: libvtkRenderingContextOpenGL2.so.1: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
marvin@X1-18:~/Applications/UVLM/release$ ldd uvlm
linux-vdso.so.1 (0x00007ffc02d56000)
libgomp.so.1 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgomp.so.1 (0x00007ff20e96e000)
libpthread.so.0 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpthread.so.0 (0x00007ff20e74f000)
libvtkViewsContext2D-7.1.so.7.1 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libvtkViewsContext2D-7.1.so.7.1 (0x00007ff20e53b000)
libvtkIOGeometry-7.1.so.7.1 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libvtkIOGeometry-7.1.so.7.1 (0x00007ff20e1f9000)
libvtkRenderingContextOpenGL2.so.1 => not found
libvtkViewsCore.so.1 => not found
libvtkInteractionWidgets.so.1 => not found
libvtkInteractionStyle.so.1 => not found
libvtkIOLegacy.so.1 => not found
libvtkIOCore.so.1 => not found
libvtkRenderingContext2D.so.1 => not found
libvtkRenderingFreeType.so.1 => not found
libfreetype.so.6 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libfreetype.so.6 (0x00007ff20df45000)
libvtkRenderingOpenGL2.so.1 => not found
libvtkRenderingCore.so.1 => not found
libvtkFiltersSources.so.1 => not found
libvtkFiltersGeneral.so.1 => not found
libvtkFiltersCore.so.1 => not found
libSM.so.6 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libSM.so.6 (0x00007ff20dd3d000)
libICE.so.6 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libICE.so.6 (0x00007ff20db22000)
libX11.so.6 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libX11.so.6 (0x00007ff20d7e9000)
libXext.so.6 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libXext.so.6 (0x00007ff20d5d7000)
libXt.so.6 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libXt.so.6 (0x00007ff20d36e000)
libvtkCommonExecutionModel.so.1 => not found
libvtkCommonDataModel.so.1 => not found
libvtkCommonMisc.so.1 => not found
libvtkCommonTransforms.so.1 => not found
libvtkCommonMath.so.1 => not found
libvtkCommonCore.so.1 => not found
libstdc++.so.6 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libstdc++.so.6 (0x00007ff20cfe0000)
libm.so.6 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libm.so.6 (0x00007ff20cc42000)
libgcc_s.so.1 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgcc_s.so.1 (0x00007ff20ca2a000)
libc.so.6 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6 (0x00007ff20c639000)
libdl.so.2 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libdl.so.2 (0x00007ff20c435000)
/lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2 (0x00007ff20eb9e000)
libvtkViewsCore-7.1.so.7.1 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libvtkViewsCore-7.1.so.7.1 (0x00007ff20c206000)
libvtkRenderingContext2D-7.1.so.7.1 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libvtkRenderingContext2D-7.1.so.7.1 (0x00007ff20bfc0000)
libvtkRenderingCore-7.1.so.7.1 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libvtkRenderingCore-7.1.so.7.1 (0x00007ff20bae4000)
libvtkCommonCore-7.1.so.7.1 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libvtkCommonCore-7.1.so.7.1 (0x00007ff20b5b2000)
libz.so.1 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libz.so.1 (0x00007ff20b395000)
libvtkIOCore-7.1.so.7.1 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libvtkIOCore-7.1.so.7.1 (0x00007ff20b120000)
libvtkCommonExecutionModel-7.1.so.7.1 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libvtkCommonExecutionModel-7.1.so.7.1 (0x00007ff20ae63000)
libvtkCommonDataModel-7.1.so.7.1 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libvtkCommonDataModel-7.1.so.7.1 (0x00007ff20a8b6000)
libvtkCommonTransforms-7.1.so.7.1 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libvtkCommonTransforms-7.1.so.7.1 (0x00007ff20a686000)
libvtkCommonSystem-7.1.so.7.1 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libvtkCommonSystem-7.1.so.7.1 (0x00007ff20a471000)
libvtksys-7.1.so.7.1 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libvtksys-7.1.so.7.1 (0x00007ff20a22b000)
libpng16.so.16 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpng16.so.16 (0x00007ff209ff9000)
libuuid.so.1 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libuuid.so.1 (0x00007ff209df2000)
libbsd.so.0 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libbsd.so.0 (0x00007ff209bdd000)
libxcb.so.1 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libxcb.so.1 (0x00007ff2099b5000)
libvtkFiltersGeneral-7.1.so.7.1 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libvtkFiltersGeneral-7.1.so.7.1 (0x00007ff209492000)
libvtkRenderingFreeType-7.1.so.7.1 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libvtkRenderingFreeType-7.1.so.7.1 (0x00007ff2091d9000)
libvtkCommonColor-7.1.so.7.1 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libvtkCommonColor-7.1.so.7.1 (0x00007ff208fbe000)
libvtkFiltersGeometry-7.1.so.7.1 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libvtkFiltersGeometry-7.1.so.7.1 (0x00007ff208d20000)
libvtkFiltersSources-7.1.so.7.1 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libvtkFiltersSources-7.1.so.7.1 (0x00007ff208a49000)
libvtkFiltersCore-7.1.so.7.1 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libvtkFiltersCore-7.1.so.7.1 (0x00007ff20838b000)
libvtkCommonComputationalGeometry-7.1.so.7.1 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libvtkCommonComputationalGeometry-7.1.so.7.1 (0x00007ff20813d000)
libvtkCommonMath-7.1.so.7.1 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libvtkCommonMath-7.1.so.7.1 (0x00007ff207f19000)
libvtkCommonMisc-7.1.so.7.1 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libvtkCommonMisc-7.1.so.7.1 (0x00007ff207cff000)
librt.so.1 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/librt.so.1 (0x00007ff207af7000)
libXau.so.6 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libXau.so.6 (0x00007ff2078f3000)
libXdmcp.so.6 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libXdmcp.so.6 (0x00007ff2076ed000)
```

Comment: What does e.g. `find /usr -name 'libvtkViewsCore.so*` print out? I am not familiar with the .deb packages for vtk, just trying to narrow down the problem scope.

Comment: Thx for the input. I added the output to the console.

Comment: And you want your executable to be linked against the shared libraries ending with `.so.1` in the folder `release`? If so, why did you install the system-wide package in the first place?

Comment: Well. It would be great if the executable is linked against my system wide shared libraries. However, the programmer who complies the executable on his system has the shared library locally. I tryed to mimick this behaviour by copying the correctly named library files into the folder. However this fails.

Comment: And what hinders you to compile the executable on your system yourself? This would be my first attempt.

Comment: The company writing the code does not want to give me access to it...

Comment: Stack Overflow is a site for programming and development questions. This question appears to be off-topic because it is not about programming or development. See [What topics can I ask about here](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) in the Help Center. Perhaps [Super User](http://superuser.com/) or [Unix & Linux Stack Exchange](http://unix.stackexchange.com/) would be a better place to ask.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is `libvtkViewsContext2D-7.1.so.7.1` in `libvtk7.1`. If the problem is only with the library name then change the dependency of the executable:

```
$ patchelf --replace-needed libvtkViewsContext2D.so.1 libvtkViewsContext2D-7.1.so.7.1 uvlm
```

Or edit the search path of the executable:

```
$ patchelf --set-rpath /path/to/libs uvlm
```

Or override the search path during launch:

```
$ LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/path/to/libs uvlm
```

Comment: Thank you very much for those great inputs. So the second and third dont seem to work, but the first one does. I just have to do it lib by lib. I added the result on top